# animation на ios не работает

Tags: css, ios, анимация

как запустить animation на ios?

```css
.wrap{position:relative;}
input{display:none;}
label{
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:170px;
  z-index:1000;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  animation:heart 1s infinite ease-in;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.heart:after,.heart:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:#D81B60;
  border-radius:50%;
    
  animation:heart 1s infinite linear;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.heart:after{
  top:120px;
  left:120px;
  border-radius:50%;
   border-radius:200px 200px 200px 0;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.heart:before{
  top:120px;
  left:50px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border-radius:200px 200px 0px 200px;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}

#checkbox:checked ~ .heart:after{
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running;}
#checkbox:checked ~ .heart:before{
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running;}
#checkbox:checked ~ label{
   -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes heart{
  from{ 
     width:300px;
     height:200px;
  }
  50%{
     width:310px;
     height:210px;
     font-size:33px;
  }
  to{ 
     width:300px;
     height:200px;
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrap">
     <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
      <label for="checkbox">Click me...</label>
       <div class="heart"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить еще свойства с префиксом -webkit-  - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/0c6b9zh8/

Comment: не, не работает =(